# Who manufactures 590mm BSD (EA3 | 650A | 26 x 1 3/8) alloy touring rims?

Tags: rims, wheel-building

I am trying to ask the question in a way that it can be answered. I am not asking who makes the best rim of this size.

Features:
 - In the triangle of price, weight and durability the last one is most important for my question but the list of manufacturers is probably not very long anyway.
 - I am planning to use rim brakes.

So far I have found:

1. Sun CR18 http://harriscyclery.net/itemdetails.cfm?ID=1348 (sorry for Harry's link - did not find them on manufacturer's page)
2. Araya SP-30 http://www.araya-kk.co.jp/rim/product.htm

Comment: Consider asking about the features that make a whole wheel more durable (spoke count, eyelets, double walls) rather than specific products.    Shopping questions tend to be closed for being off topic, because they're of limited use in the long term.

Comment: There aren't many choices in 650A; the Sun rim is probably the choice you're actually going to be able to find. I think depending on your braking system, you can do a 650A-> 650B conversion (borrow a set of 650B wheels from your bike shop and see if you can get the brakes to adjust to fit on the bike). Then, you have a ton of options in 650B these days.

Comment: You can add Weinmann ZAC2000 (single wall al), any number of junky steel ones, and one or two companies that sell somewhat nicer Westwood type 590 rims. At some point there was a company making fancy stainless steel Westrick style rims in 590 and maybe some other sizes, but I can't find anything about them now. Probably for most intents and purposes the CR18 is going to be as good as it gets here.

Comment: Sun Ringle CR-18s are probably the only double wall rim you will find in that size, weinmann makes several but they are all single walled, as will be any steel wheels in that size.

Answer (score 2):

All I see are a Sun Ringle CR-18 and a cheap steel rim from Wheel Master.  The CR-18 is definitely the stronger of those, it's a double-wall with eyelets.  If you're looking for durability, those are very good.

Answer (score 1):

SunXCD do a lovely double-wall 650A rim. You can find it at Grand Bois and their distributors

https://cyclesgrandbois.com/SHOP/SUNxcd_650A.html